# Column of Total Average Power BI

Tags: powerbi

got stuck with this one for a while. Need to repeat 165608547,90 in a Separate Column. Simple AVERAGEX(Sales[Turnover]) does not work. Thank you for any help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This would be best achieved through using a DAX measure.

```
Avg Cost = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('YourTable'[Amount]), ALL('YourTable'))
```

As per the comments added, if you want existing slicers to be respected, use [ALLSELECTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax) in place of ALL. In some cases [ALLEXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allexcept-function-dax) could also be a solution.

Note, this must be a measure and not a column.

This measure will provide the average for everything in the table when it is added as a field in the matrix/table. The ALL keyword removes any filters applied to the data during the calculation.

See [DAX ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax)

Comment: Does not work, I get a completely wrong result for Average: CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(VALUES(Dates[Year]),[Sales Total]),ALL(Dates)) and I get 330894451 as a value

Comment: Just to Mention, Year range is dynamic and Filtered through a slicer, Maybe this causes the values to differ so miuch

Comment: Try with ALLSELECTED in place of ALL.

Comment: Correct - as per mkRabbani - AllSELECTED should do the trick.